# als solche, verb situation

Tags: grammar-identification, comma

> Die Arkanspäne sind das letzte Überbleibsel unserer damaligen Beherrschungsmagie und **als solche,** können sie uns vielleicht bei der Erschaffung eines neuen Artefakts helfen, mit dessen Macht wir die Kontrolle zurückerlangen werden.

what's the comma after als solche and a verb start afterwards situation here? Could it be a mistake? someone said that there shouldn't be a comma there then the verb wouldn't be in first pos. is that it? Or is there something else going on? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The comma is a mistake, yes. The verb is in second position and the Konjunktionalphrase "als solche" takes first position.

> Als Lehrer bist du nicht geeignet. (You're not fit to be a teacher)